# Decision Problem Algorithm

Tags: decision-problem

I have a question: Every Decision problem has a method, turing machine or algorithm to solve it? If the answer is not, Could show me any example?

Answer (score 3):

A decision problem has a yes/no answer. If such a problem has an algorithm then it is called "decidable". So you are looking for undecidable problems. Happy googling.